# Aspas simples e duplas dando erro no PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$db -> setQuery("
INSERT INTO sir_ter_historico (idcorretor,data,alteracao)
VALUES ($id, '$data', '$_POST['form']['numero']');
");
$db->execute();
```

Só que dá erro, por causa das aspas simples no `'$_POST['form']['numero']'`.

Como posso fazer para resolver isso?

Comment: Pode colocar entre { }, por ex: ($id, '$data', '{$_POST['form']['numero']}');

Comment: show, obrigado!

Comment: Essa forma é bem errada de fazer, mesmo colocando `{}` não é ideal, esse `$db` é o que ???

Comment: @VirgilioNovic se estiver falando de bindParams concordo

Comment: É isso @GuilhermeNascimento mas, como não sabemos que variável é essa `$db` a solução que o usuário espera sempre a mais rápida, e ainda recebendo votos positivos ... !!! incrivel!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic sim, esses upvotes frees são um baita problema na comunidade, a maior parte que vota assim realmente não tem conhecimento razoavel na linguagem, mas já cansei de brigar contra isto. Se o autor editar a pergunta e detalhar as tecnologias talvez eu reabra ela e lhe aviso.

Comment: A pergunta foi sobre a segurança de inserir aquilo ou como inserir?

Comment: @DiegoSchmidt o problema é como inserir, mas se existem outros problemas, eles **devem ser citados**, principalmente quando se trata da segurança da aplicação. O propósito do site é discutir soluções aos problemas e, por ventura, encontrar a melhor solução, não entregar *código que funciona*, como assistencialismo.

Comment: @DiegoSchmidt independente da pergunta ser sobre **X** ou **Y** não nos impede de indicar o caminho ideal, afinal de contas não porque algo funciona que é a maneira ideal para se trabalhar. Assistencialismo por assistencialismo apenas é um grande problema na comunidade, devemos optar sempre que possivel por indicar as melhores "vias"

Comment: o $db é para fazer conexão no banco de dados. O "{" funcionou certinho

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Apenas quis ajudar de uma força rápida, não ligo pra upvote, espero realmente que alguém de uma resposta completa. Abraços.

Comment: @DiegoSchmidt eu entendo perfeitamente, mas estamos apenas tentando lhe apontar algo para melhorar neste quesito ;)

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo mas $db é um framework?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, peço desculpas pelo ocorrido então. Muito obrigado, abraços!